# C++ : First User Input Prompt Is Skipped

Tags: c++, class, prompt, getline

Could I please have help with my code. It is for a class Animal , where the user enters descriptions for a set number of body parts.
I have initialised the data members and class methods correctly,  I believe.
It is within the void create() method that a prompt, the first one is not coming up when I run the program
It's all working except for that one prompt.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Animal{
    char birth[20];
    char legs[20];
    char eyes[20];
    char ears[20];
    char mouth[20];
    char nose[20];
    public:
    void create(){
        cout<<"Describe your animal"<<endl;

        cout<"Which animal are you?: ";
        cin.getline(birth, 20);
        cout<<"Could you describe your legs?: ";
        cin.getline(legs, 20);
        cout<<"How good are your eyes?: ";
        cin.getline(eyes, 20);
        cout<<"And your sense of hearing?: ";
        cin.getline(ears, 20);
        cout<<"Can i know what your mouth looks like?: ";
        cin.getline(mouth, 20);
        cout<<"Lastly I'd like to about your nose: ";
        cin.getline(nose, 20);
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"I am a "<<birth<<endl;
    };
    void move(){
        cout<<"My legs are "<<legs<<endl;
    };
    void see(){
        cout<<"My eyes are "<<eyes<<endl;
    };
    void hear();
    void eat();
    void smell();
};

void Animal::hear(){
    cout<<"My hearing is "<<ears<<endl;
}
void Animal::eat(){
    cout<<"My mouth is "<<mouth<<endl;
}
void Animal::smell(){
    cout<<"My nose is "<<nose<<endl;
}

int main(){
    cout<<"\tDescribe Animal Chareteristics"<<endl<<endl;

    Animal eagle;
    eagle.create();
    eagle.move();
    eagle.hear();
    eagle.eat();
    eagle.smell();

}
```

When I run it skips the "Which animal are you" prompt.I don't know, I think I am missing something , that is why it is being skipped

Thank you for the help

Comment: there is an '<' missing in cout.It should be `cout<<"which animal are you?"`

Comment: You should have gotten an error from the compiler about that line. I can't even get it to compile.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` for text, rather than character arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a left angle bracket missing after cout on that line.

Comment: Don't post real answers for trivial typos.

Comment: I am new to Stack Overflow - can you point me in the direction of this rule, I must have missed it.

Comment: I don't know if it's written down explicitly anywhere. But we have a close reason for typos, so these questions should just be closed with that reason. When you get enough reputation you'll be able to vote to close.

Comment: It's in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Questions about a problem that was caused by a typo are off-topic. Off-topic questions shouldn't be answered.